# Calling a method within a dynamically named object

Tags: node.js

I am trying to invoke a method of a dynamically named object.

I have a few objects each containing a method named 'getWeight'. I need to invoke this method of a subset of these objects. However, the subset of objects depends on user inputted info, which is why I'm attempting to dynamically construct the object name and invoke it's 'getWeight' method within a loop.

My code is below:

```
// Importing objects containing 'getWeight' method
const Apple = require('../classses/Apple');
const Pear = require('../classes/Pear);
const Carrot = require('../classes/Carrot);
const Potato = require('../classes/Potato);

const promises = {};
const user = 'userX';  // This is the inputted info, could also equal 'userY'.
const searchableFoods = {
  userX: ['Apple', 'Pear'],
  userY: ['Carrot', 'Potato']
};

for (i = 0; i < searchableFoods[user].length; ++i) {
  promises[searchableFoods[user][i]] = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    // Below line should behave like: Apple.getWeight(arg1, function....
    searchableFoods[user][i].getWeight(arg1, function(response) {
      resolve(response);
    })
  })
}
```

Unfortunately, I get this error:

```
[searchableFoods[user][i].getweight] is not a function
```

I've tried a number of variations but can't make it work. Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Require all of those into a *single object* rather than many standalone variables, and then you can use simple property lookup to get to the appropriate `require`ed value. Also, `forEach` will likely result in more readable code, and you can pass the function name alone (`resolve`) rather than defining an extra anonymous function for the `getWeight` callback:

```
const foods = {
  Apple: require('../classses/Apple'),
  Pear: require('../classes/Pear),
  Carrot: require('../classes/Carrot),
  Potato: require('../classes/Potato)
};

// ...

searchableFoods[user].forEach((foodName) => {
  promises[foodName] = new Promise((resolve) => {
    foods[foodName].getWeight(arg1, resolve);
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This is the right answer. Thanks for the forEach and resolve tips.

Answer (score 1):

Can you define array not using strings? Something like that?

```
const searchableFoods = {
  userX: [Apple, Pear],
  userY: [Carrot, Potato]
};
```

Comment: Thanks Vladimir. Unfortunately the promises don't work using this.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to access `getWeight` as a property of string `'Apple'` and not of the actual object `Apple` that you are importing.

Change the subset array to something like this

```
const searchableFoods = {
  userX: [Apple, Pear],
  userY: [Carrot, Potato]
};
```

Which makes the final code to be

```
const Apple = require('../classses/Apple');
const Pear = require('../classes/Pear);
const Carrot = require('../classes/Carrot);
const Potato = require('../classes/Potato);

const promises = {};
const user = 'userX'  // This is the inputted info, could also equal 'userY'.
const searchableFoods = {
  userX: [Apple, Pear],
  userY: [Carrot, Potato]
};

for (i = 0; i < searchableFoods[user].length; ++i) {
  promises[searchableFoods[user][i]] = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    // Below line should behave like: Apple.getWeight(arg1, function....
    searchableFoods[user][i].getWeight(arg1, function(response) {
      resolve(response);
    })
  })
}
```

Comment: Thanks Revanth. Unfortunately the promises don't work using this.